# How to seed rails database using entries from other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

I have a single seed file for seeding my database. I have a bunch of currencies that I seed with a loop and I save each to a variable:

```
   currency = FactoryBot.create(:currency)
   currencies << currency
```

Then I seed users in the same file. When I seed users, I pass the `currencies` to the method so that the random one can be chosen.

A coworker suggested that I split the users and currency seeds into separate files, but now I can't get the seeds to work.

If in the user's seed file, I put `currencies = Currency.all` then I get an ActiveRecord Relation and the seeds fail. Even if I just get a list of currency ids, I'm still getting an `AssociationTypeMismatch: Currency(#70177725548980) got #<ActiveRecord::Relation`

Is it possible to split these seeds into 2 different files and still have it function?

Comment: You can call load 'seed2' for example. There might be better alternatives though

Comment: I have two seed files and don't have a problem having both seed files run. The problem in strictly accessing the existing table entries (not as an ActiveRecord Relation)